# Update nested property that is initially null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a field in a document that is potentially null; I want to update an inner field of that document, creating the field as an object if it's null. As a demonstration:

```
say the document looks like this: {
    id: "xyz",
    name: null
}

db.update({id: "xyz"}, {$set: {"name.first": "Joe"}})
```

Now, at runtime I don't know whether the name field is null or not. I just want to update `name` to be `{ first: "Joe" }` if `name` was null.

I'm actually doing this through a Mongoose Model, whose schema is as such:

```
{
    name: {
         default: null,
         type: {
            first: {
                type: String
            },
            middle: {
                type: String,
            },
            last: {
                type: String,
            },
            display: {
                type: String,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to perform the update in one query? Or do I need to do it in two steps (query to get the current value of `name`, then augment it and set it)?

EDIT: Here's what I get when I run it in the console

```
> db.users.findAndModify({ query: { _id: ObjectId("596958d60782a56eb3ba3d93") },  update: { '$set': { 'name.display': 'dfgdfgfgf' } }})
2017-07-14T20:13:45.855-0400 findAndModifyFailed failed: {
"value" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("596958d60782a56eb3ba3d93"),
    "sessionID" : "2bPzS2lqkDxN-3XEQRw60GAB93XODi4Y",
    "profilePhotoURL" : null,
    "name" : null,
    "__v" : 0
},
"errmsg" : "exception: cannot use the part (name of name.display) to traverse the element ({name: null})",
"code" : 16837,
"ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:614

> db.users.update({ _id: ObjectId("596958d60782a56eb3ba3d93") }, {$set: {"name.display": "sdfsdfsfd"}})
WriteResult({
"nMatched" : 0,
"nUpserted" : 0,
"nModified" : 0,
"writeError" : {
    "code" : 16837,
    "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (name of name.display) to traverse the element ({name: null})"
}
})
```

Comment: Why do you think the statement you demonstrate in the question would not update the name exactly like you ask? It is in fact exactly what it does! Unless you are unsure how to query for `null` as an existing property that is. But that seems a very basic thing.

Comment: Edited to add the errors I'm getting. Maybe I'm misinterpreting the error, but it sounds like it's saying it can't traverse into `null`.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently stumbled upon the same problem, and I managed to resolve it using the [aggregation pipeline for updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) feature shipped with Mongodb starting with version 4.2, and the [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator.

As an example, if I have the following document:

```
db.test.insertOne({ _id: "foo", a: null })
```

And I wanted to set a to be an object, for example:

```
a: { b: 1 }
```

You could use the following statement:

```
db.test.updateOne({_id: "foo"}, [{$set: {'a.b': { $ifNull: [1, 1] } } }])
```

What this does is that, in case 'a.b' is or isn't null, it will update it with the value 1. This approach removes the need to previously know if the field is null or if it is already initialized.

Comment: I don't think you actually need the `$ifNull` expression, merely switching to the aggregation pipeline update w/ the wrapping array works ok. https://mongoplayground.net/p/DAc-UkXrRxE

Answer (score -1):

With MongoDB you can use [findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) which will allow you to perform a query and update only the matching documents.

The operation is performed atomically, so once found no other operation can read the document until the update happened. This is useful in other circumstances. That's also why you have `writeConcern` tunable in the API.

**Example:**

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
 query: {
  name: null
 },
 update: {
  name: { first: "Joe" }
 }
})
```

Comment: I see the difference: you're updating with an object, I'm trying to update with a path string ("name.first": "Joe")

Comment: this is not recommended if the root node(here `name`) could contain other keys since this would overwrite the whole `name` node and destroy other keys if present inside the `name` node